# For which value of k will the vector be a combination of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For which value of $k$ will the vector
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\k\end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear combination of the vectors $w=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}$?

---

I am required to solve this by performing row operations. I came up with this:
$$\begin{bmatrix} -2& 0 &-1 &0 \\ 0 &-2& 1 &0 \\ k &0 &-4 &0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you tell where you're stuck at?

Comment: I am required to solve this by performing row operations. 

I came up with this 
-2 0 -1   0
0 -2   1  0
k  0   -4  0

Comment: considere these numbers a a 3x4 matrix

Comment: @egreg can you help me?

Comment: @DietrichBurde What about $k=-8$?

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the linear system
$$
\alpha\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}+
\beta\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\k\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is
$$
\begin{cases}
2\alpha+3\beta=1\\
-\alpha=-2\\
-5\alpha-2\beta=k
\end{cases}
$$
The second equation says $\alpha=2$, the first that $4+3\beta=1$ or $\beta=-1$.

Then $k=\dots$

---

If you have to solve it by row operations,
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & -2\\
-5 & -2 & k
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 1/2\\
-1 & 0 & -2\\
-5 & -2 & k
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_1\gets \frac{1}{2}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 3/2 & -3/2\\
-5 & -2 & k
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets R_2+R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 3/2 & -3/2\\
0 & -11/2 & k+5/2
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+5R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -11/2 & k+5/2
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets \frac{2}{3}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 1/2\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & k+8
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+\frac{11}{2}R_2
\end{align}

So $k=\dots$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
$$
\color{green}{2}\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\-5\end{bmatrix}\color{blue}{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\\color{red}{-8}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, $k=-8$ is the answer, but you need to do the following in terms of row reductions:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&3&1\\-1&0&-2\\-5&-2&k\end{bmatrix}\sim\cdots\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\color{green}{2}\\0&1&\color{blue}{-1}\\0&0&\color{red}{k}+8\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I'll let you fill in the middle part.